# Issues related to variable dimensions when I create a netcdf file with xarray

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to create a netcdf file from a xarray dataset which comes from a pandas data frame.

Apparently, the problem come from the fact that my variable `conca['BA']` is not recognized as a two dimensions variable.

I tried to reshape it but I am currently facing a wall.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr #pour les netCDF
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cart
import netCDF4 as nc

folder_path = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 

def build_nc(ds, file_name):
    f = nc.Dataset('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' + file_name, mode='w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
    # f is the newly created file

    f.createDimension('lon', len(ds['lon']))
    f.createDimension('lat', len(ds['lat']))

    longitude = f.createVariable('lon', 'f4', 'lon')
    latitude = f.createVariable('lat', 'f4', 'lat')
    BA_m2 = f.createVariable('BA', 'f4', ('lat', 'lon'))

    longitude[:] = ds['lon'].values
    latitude[:] = ds['lat'].values
    BA_m2[:] = ds['BA'].values

    f.description = "surface brûlée"
    longitude.units = "degrees east"
    latitude.units = "degrees north"
    BA_m2.units = "km2 brûlé"

       f.close()

dfs = []

for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)):
        print(file_name)
        ds = xr.open_dataset(folder_path + file_name)
        ds = ds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
        ds = ds[['lat','lon','burntFractionAll']]
        ds['burntFractionAll'] = ds['burntFractionAll']/100
        ds = ds.groupby(['lon','lat'])['burntFractionAll'].mean()
        dfs.append(ds)
        del ds

del folder_path

conca = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)

del dfs

#On renomme burntFractionAll en burntfractionall par BA_100

conca = conca.to_frame().reset_index()
conca = conca.groupby(['lon','lat'])['burntFractionAll'].mean()
conca = conca.to_frame().reset_index()
conca['BA_100'] = conca['burntFractionAll']*29.5

rad = abs(np.cos(np.abs(conca['lat'])*0.0174))  # cos(lat*0.0174)
surf_area = rad*1239  # cos(lat)*cell_area_2 km2 [1°*1°]
conca['BA'] = conca['BA_100'] * surf_area
conca['BA'] = conca['BA'] * 0.001# km2 to Mha car 1 ha = 10000 m2

conca = conca.set_index(['lon','lat']).to_xarray()
conca['BA'] = conca['BA'].values.reshape(len(conca['lat']), len(conca['lon']))
build_nc(conca, file_name)
```

I tried to force the creation of a two dimensional variables and I tried to create another xarray dataset.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using Xarray to create your NetCDF file. I recommend creating an `xarray.Dataset` with your processed data then saving that dataset using the `ds.to_netcdf()` method. You'll find that to be much easier than setting up your own NetCDF file.

Comment: You might also be able to use `xarray.open_mfdataset()` to open all your files at once instead of looping through the folders.